# C#, Read CSV for repeated cell values in 2 columns, count how many times something appears, add 1 to it and append it to a string for number increment

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

Basically, I have a friendly name generator that consist of Project Name_Project Build_, and a number at the end indicating that its for example 3rd of 3 total of same project and build. Example: This is what I have in CSV File: the number at the end keeps incrementing counting rows +1.
[image]
Project Name, Project Build
Toyota, 2007
Toyota, 2007

Friendly name = Toyota_2007_01 > where 1 indicates that Toyota and 2007 only appears once in same row.
Adding 1 more Toyota 2007, would generate a friendly name: Toyota_2007_02 where 02 indicates that there are 2 of same Toyota 2007 in the csv so if I add next, it will append 03 for the 3rd entry

This is what the csv should have now:

(csv Header)

Project Name, Project Build, Friendly Name.

Toyota, 2007, Toyota_2007_01.

Toyota, 2007, Toyota_2007_02

If I add a different project in the same csv in the next available row,

Honda              2009

than code should find that Honda and 2009 in "same row" only appears once so friendly name should be Honda_2009_01....

My code already generates the friendly name up to "build year" but I want it to actually go in the csv, read it and find how may time project name and build year appear in same row and count, than add 1 to append that number at the end depending on how many of those things are in the file.

Here is the Code so far.

some code above...
{
// counting lines in CSV file
// This method counts the number of Rows in the File skipping over the header row assigns value to variable, increments by 1 for next entry

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) // true for appending data to file, false to overwrite in file
        {
            if (headerLine)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(header);
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format(projectName + "," + projetcBuild.ToString() + "," + projectSN.ToString()));
            }
            else if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format(projectName + "," + projetcBuild.ToString() + "," + projectSN.ToString()));
            }
            
        }



        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\LOG.csv");
        string headerLine = file.ReadLine();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        string FreindlyName = ProjectName_TextBox.Text + "_" + ProjectBuild_TextBox.Text + "_" + counter;
        file.Close();
```

The CSV should have, this

[image]

I hope I did not over explain this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is you data come from ?

Comment: User inputs Project Name, Project Build..

Comment: you did not choose the best way to do it or I didn't understand the problem.
are you trying to just update your log file?

Comment: Or is the counter calculation your problem ?

Comment: So there is a GUI, it takes 2 parameters, Project name and Build. When user enters the 2, it goes to CSV under Project Name, and Project Build columns. Since there will be multiple entries over some time, I would like to have a way to see how may of Toyota 2007 cars are in the log. This is where the Code goes and reads the log for two same things in two columns and counts them.

Comment: So my CSV will have a thirds column titled "Friendly name" which takes the first Column_Second Column_#. the number at the end is like an unique ID so if there is like 4 same records than there would be 4 freindly names with 01,02,03, and 04 append at the end.

Comment: I would like to have my code match the user inputs > Read the CSV log file > see if there are existing records of same Name and Build > if there are lets say 5 records under same user entry than the new entry will get a friendly name with 06 appended at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I noticed your counter is totally wrong. I just fixed your counter hope this can solve your problem.

```cs
    string line;
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\LOG.csv");
    string headerLine = file.ReadLine() ;
    
    var counter = new List<string>();
    while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( (line = file.ReadLine()) ))
    {
        var cells = line.Split(','); // use your seprator => ,  |
        var projectFullName = $"{cells[0]}_{cells[1]}"; // eg Toyota_2007
        counter.Add(projectFullName);
    }
    var newName = ProjectName_TextBox.Text + "_" + ProjectBuild_TextBox.Text
    var newCount = counter.Where(q=> q == newName).Count() + 1;

    string freindlyName = $"{newName}_{newCount.ToString("00")}"; // freindlyName with correct number
    file.Close();
```

---

UPDATE:

A better counter.

just add this function to your code and use it to get correct count of your records.

```cs
public int CountFromLogFile(string projectName, string projectBuild, char seprator ,string csvPath)
{
    var isHeader = true;
    var counterDic = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(csvPath))
    {
        if (isHeader)
        {
            isHeader = false;
            continue;
        }
        var cells = line.Split(seprator); // 0 => projectName & 1 => projectBuild
        var fName = $"{cells[0]}_{cells[1]}";
        if (counterDic.ContainsKey(fName))
            counterDic[fName]++;
        else
            counterDic.Add(fName,0);
    }
    var qName = $"{projectName}_{projectBuild}";
    return counterDic.ContainsKey(qName) ? counterDic[qName] : 0 ;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var count = CountFromLogFile(ProjectName_TextBox.Text , ProjectBuild_TextBox.Text , ',' , @"C:\LOG.csv");
```

Comment: import required namespaces. like `using System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic` etc.
CTRL+. on error should fix that for you

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you your edits. I implemented the changes above but now its not recording the friendly name at all.

Comment: I've just updated your code with correct number for friendlyName variable.
in your sample code, you didn't save friendlyName anyware.

Comment: Sorry, I added friendlyName to column now, it records the name. Issue I see is that the code above is in a separate method and where I create and store data in csv is in another. So I made FreindlyName a global variable, put it outside of above method so I can use it and append it on my csv method.

Comment: Hi Ali, for your updated method, what do you mean add this to my code.

Comment: you are not using friendlyName in above code. 
`sw.WriteLine(string.Format(projectName + "," + projetcBuild.ToString() + "," + projectSN.ToString()));`

where you wanna use friendlyName then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234461/discussion-between-jabir-and-alireza).